# How do I delete a table from the MySQL Workbench catalog?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Recently I started using MySQL Workbench to design my data structures with an UML diagram. However, there is one thing I could figure out.

It seems that if I delete a table from the EER-diagram view, the table persists in the catalog view (as illustrated by the screenshot below). I could find a way to delete from the catalog view and it still list in the foreign key table reference selection screen.

This is very confusing. How can I effectively remove the table (not only from the view but from the whole project?

[image: workbench]

Notice, the two question tables one of which I deleted in the view and redesigned.

Comment: If you deleted it from the catalog, the other parts probably just need a "Refresh" to catch up changes.

Comment: already tried that with no luck, I deleted it from the diagram, but those changes do not reflect in the catalog even after an refreh in that menu (it doesnt contain a delete option)

Comment: Throw it back in the Diagram. Then delete it from there. It will ask you if "corresponding objects be deleted with the figures" (two choices: Delete or Keep). Choose **Delete**

Comment: In my case, it doesn't work. Just restart mysql workbench it work.

Comment: If you throw it back in the diagram and it has no relationships, then add one and then delete the table from the diagram. This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just had this problem before.

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> / <kbd>delete</kbd> on the keyboard will *only delete the figure* in the designer.

To completely delete the table and figure, instead try: `Right-click > Delete 'table'`.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqAWC.png]

Comment: I'd like to add that this solution, or any of the others mentioned here, did not work for me in version 6.2.x.

After updating to 6.3.3 this solution does work, thank you.

Comment: How do you do this if you cannot see the table in the diagram? It shows up in the catalog, but right clicking in the catalog only gives `Edit Table` as an option. Your picture shows you right-clicking a visible table in the diagram.

Comment: Anjana Silva's answer answered my question.

Answer (score 46):

**In case if the right-click and delete didn't work,**

Simply drag and drop the table from the Catalog Tree to the Design area. Then you will see the table gets inserted there. From there, right-click on the table and select delete table. Then the table will get deleted from the whole project (assuming correspondent objects which are needed deleting as well).

Comment: This tip saved me hours of frustration. I had a table in the catalogue view that did not appear in the ERM diagram. It was preventing me from synchronising. With your tip I was able to delete it.

Comment: Real hero here!

Answer (score 5):

I am using "MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Mac OS X version 6.2.3  revision 12313 build 2282 (32 bit)" and the action "delete 'table'" in the context menu (right-click on the table) did not work for me.

Believe it or not I had to restart the whole application. After the restart the delete action worked as expected. (1 object(s) deleted) [nothing about the object is kept in the DB]

Comment: Yes, a restart of Workbench did the trick when all of the above solutions did not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I discovered the difference between "delete" and "remove figure".
The "delete" deletes tables from the whole project, the "remove figure" only from the diagram (the tables still stay in the catalog).